# How to get a nested JSON from a pandas dataframe which has multi-level index of 4 levels?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I've a pandas DataFrame with Multi-Level index of 4 levels (say Name, Year, Month, Date) and i want to make a nested JSON from this DataFrame which has 2 columns namely, col1 & col2, with arbitrary numbers.

I've tried `df.to_json()` with different 'orient' values but it doesn't give json in required nested structure.

The structure of the nested JSON should be like:
'Name' within should be 'Year' within which should be 'Month' within which should be 'Date' and then the column values in a list or dictionary. So, for the key of 'Year' we will have 12 months objects, and so on.

Comment: Hello and welcome on Stack Overflow. Please give a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing what you have tried.

Comment: See how to make a good pandas question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples